# Positivity of solution to Laplace equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying PDE and at the moment I'm reading L. Evans' book.

The strong maximum principle states that; if $u\in C^2(U)\cup C(\bar U)$ is harmonic in $U$, where $U$ is connected and if there exists $x_0$ such that $u(x_0)=\max _\bar U u$, then $u$ is constant within $U$.

A little later Evans states that if $U$ is connected and $u$ is a solution of the pde $\Delta u=0$ in $U$ and $u=g$ on $\partial U$, where $g\geq 0$. Then $u$ is positive in $U$ everywhere if $g$ is positive somewhere on $\partial U$.

Why is this true? I can't see how this follows immediately from the strong maximum principle. I'm guessing it is trivial and I'm just over thinking it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: It's actually easy to see using brownian motion on the domain $U$ but I imagine you want a "pde"s like answer.

Comment: @muaddib Sorry for replying to this old comment, but do you've got a reference for a proof using Brownian motion at hand?

Comment: Just apply Dynkin's Formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin%27s_formula

Comment: Then again I'm not sure why it is clear the probability of exit through the part of the boundary where the function is positive has positive density.  You would have to apply that as well.  Oksendal - Stochastic Differential Equations.

Comment: I'm thinking the following might work.  Take a path from your starting point to the boundary point where the function is positive.  Fatten this path up to be an open connected set.  Then there exists a conformal mapping to this path region (via Riemann) to the unit disk. The poisson kernel is positive everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the associated problem where $\tilde{g} = -g$ on the boundary.  Then $\tilde{u} = -u$ solves Laplace's equation with those new boundary conditions.  So $\tilde{u}$ is everywhere non positive on the boundary (negative somewhere) but has point in the interior of $U$ where it is non negative.  That violates the maximum principle because either $U$ is a constant (hence zero everywhere - which is impossible) or $\tilde{u}$ attains its max only on the boundary.  Hence, $\tilde{u}$ is negative everywhere in the interior which means $u$ is everywhere positive in the interior.

Comment: What if we changed the problem so that we have $\Delta u = g$ in $U$ and $u = 0$ on $\partial U$, where $g \ge 0$?

Comment: So $u\ge 0$, right? But the statement says $u\gt 0$ in $U$.

Comment: I rewrote the answer - thanks for the comment.